hev1 vs hvc1 - which is better?
I have several MP4 videos that is a mix of hev1 and hvc1 codecs. Some of the playback devices are iPhones.
Is it better to tag them as hev1 or hvc1?

hvc1 is better because macOS apps like QuickTime Player do not support video codec H.265 with Codec ID hev1.
ffmpeg can losslessly and very fast fix that H.265 with Codec ID hev1 issue with:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -tag:v hvc1 output.mp4

ffmpeg does not properly support copying metadata so you might want to copy it from the original with:
exiftool -m -overwrite_original -api QuickTimeUTC=1 -api LargeFileSupport=1 -tagsFromFile input.mp4 -All:All '-FileCreateDate<QuickTime:CreateDate' '-FileModifyDate<QuickTime:CreateDate' output.mp4

On the other hand IINA and VLC should have no issues with playing any decent new or old codec.
